# Slidingmenu on both sides

Tags: android, button, slidingmenu

I am Completely new to android and i've been given a task of having sliding menus on click of a buttons placed on either side of the corners. Very similar to that of Facebook app. I tried using the SherlockAction bar library and the Slidingmenu library but I don't quite understand its functioning. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use ABS with SlidingMenu first of all go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend Sherlock__*Activity instead of _*_Activity.

Then simply try:

```
public class FragmentsHolderActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    public static boolean isChangeCategoryAllow = true;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    public MenuItem mRefreshMenuItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();    
                sm.setFadeEnabled(false);
                sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
                sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
                sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
                sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);


        // set the Above View
        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

         //add if you need dinamically customize your fragment as your liking.
        /*getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new CategoryImagesListFragment())
        .commit();*/

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

        //add if you need dinamically customize the SlidingMenu as your liking.
        /*getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new CategoryFragment())
        .commit();  */
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toggle();
                return true;          
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**setBehindContentView** will place the view in the "behind" portion of the SlidingMenu.